# How did the Jedi find out Darth Maul's name?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, the-clone-wars

How did the Jedi Order find out Darth Maul's name?

Comment: Obi-Wan knew it in season 4 of the Clone Wars, and the Jedi say it in various novels.

Comment: Jedi spy network...

Comment: Facial recognition. They ran a photo of him on Google Image search and it brought up his Facebook.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There's no canon confirmation, but don't forget that The Republic took Separatist leader Nute Gunray (and his extensive entourage) into custody following the Trade Federation’s defeat on Naboo.

> **DARTH SIDIOUS :** (Cont'd) *...Viceroy, this is my apprentice,* **Lord
>   Maul**. *He will find your lost ship.*
>
> **NUTE :** *Yes, My Lord.*
>
> The hologram fades off.
>
> **NUTE :** (Cont'd) *This is getting out of hand... now there are two of
>   them.* - <sub><sup>[The Phantom Menace](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Star-Wars-The-Phantom-Menace.html)</sup></sub>

Nute and his men knew Maul's name, and after having had to face four (inconclusive) trials, there's no reason to assume that one of them didn't share this not-especially secret information with their captors.

---

According to the Lucasfilm Licenced RPG "[The Dark Side Sourcebook](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/The_Dark_Side_Sourcebook)", Maul also left his ship on Naboo near the palace where it was ultimately...

> "Recovered by the Republic authorities on Naboo after his death".

It's certainly possible that a search of his ship gave them his name, perhaps on a rental agreement or a parking badge.

Comment: +1, but Sith park wherever they want. If there was a rental agreement, I can imagine a dispute between the rental company and the Republic authorities who wanted to impound Maul's ship as evidence. :-)

Comment: Nice answer, but come on, "rental agreement or a parking badge"? Like he would sign it "Darth Maul" instead of something like "Totally Inconspicuous Dude With A Lightsaber" or any other mundane name. No, the ship is dead end for sure. Nute and his crew (or some evidence like security recordings or logs) are much more likely.

Comment: I bet he had vanity plates. Should have gone with [1I1-III11](http://xkcd.com/1105/) instead of STHRLZ.

Comment: Why are we assuming that he was trying to keep it a secret in the first place? The Sith love glory and all that. That's part of being on the dark side, I guess.

Comment: He signed the rental agreement as "Garth Paul" to throw them off his trail.  That's canon.

Comment: "Garth Paul", is canon?! Sounds like a stupid name to me.

Comment: One of Nute's co-horts, Hath Monchar, attempts to sell the holotape of Sidious & Maul to both the Jedi as well as Black Sun. This can be seen in the "Darth Maul: Shadow Hunter" novel and the "Star Wars: Darth Maul" comic.

Comment: @Omegacron - And did anyone buy said tape?

Comment: Well, the Black Sun vigo in the comic kicked him out and suggested he go peddle his nonsense to the Jedi. We next see him approaching some Jedi in the novel, with Maul hot on his tail, but he doesn't actually get to deal with them even though they're somewhat intrigued. If I remember right, Maul killed those Jedi and I think ultimately Palpatine got the tape, but I don't remember if anyone else heard the name during all this.